# Why can't I see TTL from db.my_collection.getIndex() output?

Tags: ruby, mongodb

I have an index with `expireAfterSeconds` set. How do I confirm this using the CLI when the output of `db.my_collection.getIndexes()` only shows this:

```
{
  "v": 1,
  "key": {
    "last_used_at": 1
  },
  "name": "last_used_at_1",
  "ns": "cms.user_sessions"
}
```

It looks just like a normal index without `expireAfterSeconds` set.

How can I confirm that an index was created with `expireAfterSeconds`?

---

Here's the Ruby code that creates the index. I have tried dropping the index and recreating it using this code several times.

```
@user_sessions.indexes.create_many([
  {key: {token: 1}, unique: true},
  {key: {last_used_at: 1}, expireAfterSeconds: ttl}
])
```

Version information:

```
$ mongod --version
db version v2.6.5
2016-07-13T16:11:45.844+0200 git version: e99d4fcb4279c0279796f237aa92fe3b64560bf6

$ gem list | grep mongo
mongo (2.2.5)
```

Answer (score 1):

there is an issue with your index, try drop it and recreate.

When TTL is set you will get that from `db.name.getIndexes()` command

```
[
    {
        "v" : 1,
        "key" : {
            "_id" : 1
        },
        "name" : "_id_",
        "ns" : "test.eventlog"
    },
    {
        "v" : 1,
        "key" : {
            "lastModifiedDate" : 1.0
        },
        "name" : "lastModifiedDate_1",
        "ns" : "test.eventlog",
        "expireAfterSeconds" : 3600.0
    }
]
```

Comment: I've tried that already. I updated my question since I don't feel like pasting several lines of code into a comment.

Comment: [According to the documentation, my MongoDB version should support expireAfterSeconds](https://docs.mongodb.com/v2.6/reference/method/db.collection.ensureIndex/#db.collection.ensureIndex), so that shouldn't be the problem.